# Java Project Reactor subscribeOn behavior for Mono chains

Tags: java, reactive-programming, project-reactor

I am learning about project reactor and get confused on some questions regarding subscribeOn()

My blocking code looks like (say getA(), getB(), getC(A, B), getD(A, B), getE(C, D) are both time complex functions)

```
public E someMethod() {
  A a = getA();
  B b = getB();
  C c = getC(a, b);
  D d = getD(a, b);
  return getE(c, d);
}
```

Now I want to change it into a unblocking implementation, I wrote

```
public E someMethodUnblocking() {
  Mono<A> a = Mono.fromCallable(getA).subscribeOn(Schedulers.boundedElastic());
  Mono<B> b = Mono.fromCallable(getB).subscribeOn(Schedulers.boundedElastic());
  Mono<C> c = Mono.zip(a, b, (aa, bb) -> getC(aa,bb)).subscribeOn(Schedulers.boundedElastic());
  Mono<D> d = Mono.zip(a, b, (aa, bb) -> getD(aa,bb)).subscribeOn(Schedulers.boundedElastic());
  return Mono.zip(c, d, (cc, dd) -> getE(cc, dd)).block()
}
```

Does this look like the correct implementation? will there be a difference if I remove the subscribeOn() when generating Mono a and b?

Comment: All getX() functions are blocking calls

Answer (score 0):

Your implementation subscribes twice to the (cold) monos a and b - and will run your costly getA() and getB() methods two times.

To avoid that, you should cache() the first two monos.